# Django app incorporation process

Tags: django, django-apps

Can some one please highlight what should be the process of incorporating reusable django app in a project without using setup.py.

Can we simply move app into project directory and start using it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as it's on `sys.path`, it will be found by Django. And yes, you can move it to project's directory.

Answer (score 2):

To add to that: if you are pretty sure you are only going to use an app once, it may be easiest just to drop it in the project directory; however, I have found that for apps I use more than once, it is easier to put in the `sys.path` (as mentioned).

Since most apps are availabale via svn or git, I tend to grab the source (trunk) this way, and then create a symbolic link into my site-packages folders (which is on `sys.path`).  This way I can continue to pull updates to the app in this folder.

I do this with the django trunk as well.

For example, I have: `~/src/django-notification` and `~/src/django-trunk`.  And I have then symbolically linked onto my python path.

```
sudo ln -s ~/src/django-notification/notification /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/notification
```

This way all my projects can import the app easily and I can continue to get updates.

Comment: But wont you end up having non stable version of apps if you use development version directly?

Comment: Sure could - but you also get the latest features.  Django trunk seems to be very stable to me and the apps I use don't get updated that often (only with bug fixes).  I am also not using this method on a production machine ... just on my development server.  I wouldn't just go about pulling new revisions on a production server without first testing them on the development server.